# How can you create a responsive, vertically and horizontally centered image with HTML and CSS3 without using background

Tags: html, image, css, center

My goal is to vertically and horizontally center an image inside its container and that the image takes as much space as possible without ever changing the original aspect ratio.

Using { background-size: contain; background-position: center; background-repeat: norepeat; } is not an option since I need to attach an overlay div to the corner of the image. Using a background would mean that the containing div would not follow the image size precisely.

Here's an attempt to do this using flexbox. Unfortunately it does not work in Firefox (on linux at least). Firefox stretches images when the width of the container is larger than the image's width for the given height. [Flexbox attempt](http://jsbin.com/reteto/6)

Here's another attempt, this time using absolute positioning w/ left: 50%; in order to center a first div and transform: translate(-50%, -50%) in order to center the image. The result is not acceptable because the image-wrapper div (with green "olivedrab" borders) is not right around the image on Firefox (same in chrome when resizing the window vertically). This means that no overlay can be attached directly on the image (and follow as it is resized). [Left 50% + Translate attempt](http://jsbin.com/vosufo/12)

Note: No Javascript should be needed.

Comment: you can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to achieve that. http://jsfiddle.net/m6ycfbkq/

Comment: @dward Though it does center that 400px by 400px image, if you resize the window, the picture does not resize down.

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/m6ycfbkq/1/

Comment: @dward: Unfortunately, this does not work in Firefox (32) and only works when resized horizontally in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
} 
</style>
```

Tested in IE9 and FF.

Comment: Nice solution! But, in fact, `div` properties other than `position:relative` and dimensions are a bit irrelevant here since all the 'magic' is done with absolute positioning of the image and `margin:auto`: http://jsbin.com/zivuyehutule/2/

Comment: Although the first example in the question does use fixed dimension divs, it's only to illustrate the problem in Firefox. The goal is for the image to be fully responsive, i.e. resize to all browser sizes. Your answer centers the image in fixed size divs, but does not work with divs having 100% width/height.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```css
div {
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Just to illustrate the example better */
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/9dc5afd0db110ad78cb81e0b1dd84ebc/7dmyfag/NGfmkucxa/tumblr_static_tyrion-lannister.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/Tyrion_Lannister-Peter_Dinklage.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Not in firefox 32 on linux, same problem as my flexbox example.